# How to check in a component with a comment (comment not appearing)

Tags: core-service

I'm trying to check in a Component (ComponentData) via the Core Service.  The issue I'm facing is that when checking the component in my userComment argument isn't getting saved.  All I see in the version history is the generic comment: "Checked-in by MyUser".

[image]

At first I thought this was because I'm logged in as an Admin user.  But I tried as a regular user and get the same generic "checked-in by" message.

Here is the code:

```
client.Save(item, readOptionsExpanded);
msg = "My custom check-in message...lalala";
client.CheckIn(id: model.TcmUri, removePermanentLock: false, userComment: msg, readBackOptions: readOptionsExpanded);
```

So my question is, is this a known bug or am I doing something wrong/not using the function correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's shown in the Comment column in the history list in the CME is the "system comment", not the "user comment". Unfortunately, the latter is not shown at all in the UI yet (but you can of course create a UI extension that shows it :-)

Comment: Rick, this is a great information to keep handy since the documentation does not says anything about whether it will appear or not in the CME :) and we can save ourselves shot in the dark if we know this

Answer (score 1):

Can you try setting `removePermanentLock` as `true` and then execute the code block and check if it solves the problem? That seems to be the only difference between code sample in Tridion documentation and your usage of the method. If that does not solves it, then it is a bug!